# List of Acronyms: only first use in numberlist and table of content style dots

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, glossaries, acronyms

I would like to display the list of acronyms in the following way:

- in the number list there should be only the page with the first use of the acronym
- the number should be aligned on the right, with a line of dots from the acronym to the number, just like in the table of content

I use the following package options:

```
\usepackage[nomain,
      acronym,
      xindy,toc, 
      section=chapter, 
      numberedsection=nolabel]{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries 
....
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: cheers for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first requirement, you can use the package option `indexonlyfirst`. Your second requirement can can be dealt with by defining a new style similar to the `listdotted` style:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[nomain,
      acronym,
      xindy,toc, 
      section=chapter, 
      numberedsection=nolabel,
      indexonlyfirst]{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries

\setlength{\glslistdottedwidth}{0.7\textwidth} % adjust to suit

\newglossarystyle{mydottedstyle}{%
 \glossarystyle{list}%
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \item[]\makebox[\glslistdottedwidth][l]{%
      \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##3 (##2)}%
      \unskip\leaders\hbox to 2.9mm{\hss.}\hfill\strut}##5}%
}

\glossarystyle{mydottedstyle}

\newacronym{sample}{short}{long}

\begin{document}

First use on page 1: \gls{sample}.

\newpage

Next use on page 2: \gls{sample}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Resulting text]

You can adjust the value of `\glslistdottedwidth` as necessary. For example

```
\setlength{\glslistdottedwidth}{0.8\textwidth}
```

It depends on how wide your acronyms are. If you only want the short form to appear in the list of acronyms, you can modify the style, like this:

```
\newglossarystyle{mydottedstyle}{%
 \glossarystyle{list}%
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \item[]\makebox[\glslistdottedwidth][l]{%
      \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}%
      \unskip\leaders\hbox to 2.9mm{\hss.}\hfill\strut}##5}%
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, `indexonlyfirst` is not documented in the user guide.

Comment: @mafp I added `indexonlyfirst` to v3.02, but it looks like I forgot to document that option. I'll add it to the user guide for the next release.

Comment: thank you very much. that's exactly what i was looking for.