# glossaries: acronyms: avoid additional entries in number list with indexonlyfirst and acrshort

Tags: glossaries

In a longer document I have places where I need to enforce the usage of defined abbreviations with e.g. `\acrshort` (tikz pictures) and want to profit of the link to the glossary capabilities.

Furthermore I use `\gls` in my text.

In the acronym glossary I would like to only give the page number of the first occurence using `indexonlyfirst`.

How may I avoid that EACH usage of `\acrshort` is listed instead ?

MWE is taken with slide modifications from [printglossary acronym, display only the first appearance of arcshort in glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197631/101663) where my point has not been conclusivly answered:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,indexonlyfirst]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{sdk}{SDK}{Software Development Kit}

\begin{document}
Test \acrshort{sdk}
\newpage
Test \acrshort{sdk}.
\newpage
Test \acrshort{sdk}\newpage
Test \newpage
Test \acrshort{sdk}\newpage
Test \newpage
Test \newpage
Test \acrshort{sdk}\newpage
Test \acrshort{sdk}\newpage
\printglossaries%y[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be easier to do with the extension package [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra). This provides extra keys and a more flexible abbreviation interface. Abbreviations are defined using `\newabbreviation[`*options*`]{`*label*`}{`*short*`}{`*long*`}` but to assist users who have pre-existing `glossaries` code, `\newacronym` is redefined to use this new interface, so `\newacronym[`*options*`]` is now equivalent to `\newabbreviation[category=acronym,`*options*`]`, but the style now needs to be set using `\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]` instead of `\setacronymstyle`. The short and long forms are now accessed using `\glsxtrshort` and `\glsxtrlong`. The original `\acrshort` and `\acrlong` commands may still be used, but they don't work properly if the document has multiple abbreviation styles. (The base `glossaries` package only allows one abbreviation style.)

The extension package also provides a new key `noindex` which can be used in the optional argument of commands like `\gls`. We can therefore take advantage of these new features to redefine `\acrshort` in terms of `\glsxtrshort` with the `noindex` key automatically set:

```
\renewcommand*{\acrshort}[1][]{\glsxtrshort[noindex,#1]}
```

Now none of your `\acrshort` commands will perform any indexing (unless this setting is overridden using `\acrshort[noindex=false]`.

Here's a modified version of your MWE. I've added a couple of `\gls` commands for comparison:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{sdk}{SDK}{Software Development Kit}

\renewcommand*{\acrshort}[1][]{\glsxtrshort[noindex,#1]}

\begin{document}
Test \acrshort{sdk}
\newpage
Test \acrshort{sdk}.
\newpage
Test \acrshort{sdk}\newpage
Test \newpage
Test \acrshort{sdk}\newpage
Test [gls] \gls{sdk}
\newpage
Test \newpage
Test [gls] \gls{sdk}
\newpage
Test \newpage
Test \acrshort{sdk}\newpage
Test \acrshort{sdk}\newpage
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The glossary now only has two entries in the location list for `sdk`.

[image: image of glossary]

These correspond to the two instances of `\gls{sdk}`. These can be dealt with through the `indexonlyfirst` package option:

```
\usepackage[indexonlyfirst]{glossaries-extra}
```

or to only apply this option to entries that have the `category` set to `acronym` (which is done by `\newacronym`):

```
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{indexonlyfirst}{true}
```

Note that the `indexonlyfirst` setting will override `noindex=false` in commands like `\gls` (but you can still use `noindex=false` for commands like `\acrshort`).

You can still use the `acronym` package option with `glossaries-extra`

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}
```

with the glossary type identified by `\acronymtype` (and `\printacronyms` as a shortcut for `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]`, or you can use the `abbreviations` package option:

```
\usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}
```

with `\printabbreviations` (the glossary type is can be identified using `\glsxtrabbrvtype`).

Here's the updated MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{indexonlyfirst}{true}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{sdk}{SDK}{Software Development Kit}

\renewcommand*{\acrshort}[1][]{\glsxtrshort[noindex,#1]}

\begin{document}
Test \acrshort{sdk}
\newpage
Test \acrshort{sdk}.
\newpage
Test \acrshort{sdk}\newpage
Test \newpage
Test \acrshort{sdk}\newpage
Test [gls] \gls{sdk}
\newpage
Test \newpage
Test [gls] \gls{sdk}
\newpage
Test \newpage
Test \acrshort{sdk}\newpage
Test \acrshort{sdk}\newpage

\printabbreviations
\end{document}
```

This produces the glossary:

[image: image of glossary]

Comment: Thank you very much for the extensive answer. I will make myself familiar with the glossaries-extra packge.