# glossaries: acronyms: How to display only the first appearance of an acronym among the Abbreviations if only its short form is used in the text?

Tags: numbering, glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I would like to display the place of the first appearance of all acronyms, used in my text, but for some acronyms I prefer to use only the short form (even for the first usage). My question is similar to [this previous one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318694/glossaries-acronyms-avoid-additional-entries-in-number-list-with-indexonlyfirs), BUT the solution for that does not allow for displaying among the Abbreviations those acronyms the long form of which was always suppressed.
I tried to solve this by adding `\glsadd` manually to the first occurrence of `\acrshort`, but this results in errors during compilation.

This is a MWE for my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{indexonlyfirst}{true}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{faq}{FAQ}{Frequently Asked Questions}
\newacronym{bbc}{BBC}{British Broadcasting Corporation}

\renewcommand*{\acrshort}[1][]{\glsxtrshort[noindex,#1]}

\begin{document}
Only short: \acrshort{faq}\\ %adding \glsadd{faq} here results in errors
Long form will be used as well: \acrshort{bbc}
\newpage
Again the short form: \acrshort{faq}\\
Normal usage: \gls{bbc}\\

\printabbreviations
\end{document}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest method is to use the `short` style for acronyms that shouldn't expand on first use and the `long-short` style for the ones that should. Since the `abbreviation` category has `long-short` as the default style and the `acronym` category has `short` as the default style, you could just use `\newacronym` for the terms that should show the full form on first use and `\newabbreviation` for the others.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{indexonlyfirst}{true}

\newacronym{faq}{FAQ}{Frequently Asked Questions}
\newabbreviation{bbc}{BBC}{British Broadcasting Corporation}

\begin{document}
Only short: \gls{faq}\\
Long form will be used as well: \gls{bbc}
\newpage
Again the short form: \gls{faq}\\
Normal usage: \gls{bbc}\\

\printabbreviations
\end{document}
```

First page:

[image: Only short: FAQ Long form will be used as well: British Broadcasting Corporation (BBC)]

Second page:

[image: Again the short form: FAQ Normal usage: BBC Abbreviations BBC British Broadcasting Corporation 1, 2 FAQ Frequently Asked Questions 1]

Since the `indexonlyfirst` attribute is only set for the `acronym` category, the FAQ entry only has one location (page 1), since it was only indexed on first use. The `abbreviation` category doesn't have this attribute set, so the BBC entry has two locations (page 1 and 2) as it was indexed on each use of `\gls`.